# Double for loop for alternation C++

Tags: c++, arrays, math, for-loop

How am i suppose to generate something like this in a double for loop? Such that the output will become something like

```
O O O O O O O O O
O 1 O 1 O 1 O 1 O
O O O O O O O O O 
O 1 O 1 O 1 O 1 O
O O O O O O O O O 
O 1 O 1 O 1 O 1 O
O O O O O O O O O 
O 1 O 1 O 1 O 1 O
O O O O O O O O O
```

My Attempt follows:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
    {
        //Insert code here
        if (j % 2 == 0)
        {
            array[b][a] = 0;
        }
        else if (i % 2 == 0 )
        {
            array[b][a] = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

I do know % is involved, but I just cant get the logic over here such that **the corner of the 2d array is all 0**, can someone please guide me through?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example you can do it the following way

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    const size_t N = 9;
    int a[N][N];

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < N; j++ ) a[i][j] = i % 2 + j % 2 == 2;
    }

    for ( auto &row : a )
    {
        for ( int x : row ) std::cout << x << ' ';
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Or you could initialize the array with zeroes as for example

```
int a[N][N] = {};
```

and then fill only odd rows of the array in loops.

For example

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    const size_t N = 9;
    int a[N][N] = {};

    for ( size_t i = 1; i < N; i += 2 )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < N; j++ ) a[i][j] = j % 2;
    }

    for ( auto &row : a )
    {
        for ( int x : row ) std::cout << x << ' ';
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program output will be the same as shown above.

Or you could write simply using in the loops only odd rows and columns.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    const size_t N = 9;
    int a[N][N] = {};

    for ( size_t i = 1; i < N; i += 2 )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 1; j < N; j += 2 ) a[i][j] = 1;
    }

    for ( auto &row : a )
    {
        for ( int x : row ) std::cout << x << ' ';
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

#### The most important thing to do FIRST is to determine the pattern!

When I look at that output, the pattern that I see is that the output is `1` when both the row and column have an odd index. Otherwise, the array has a `0`.

Note that writing this down does **not** involve code. This is just a fact written in plain english. It's very important to do this first.

#### How do we determine if a number is odd?

A number `x` is odd if `x % 2 == 1`.

#### So let's write some code:

```
bool isOdd(int x) {
    return x % 2 == 1;
}

void work() {
    int array[9][9];

    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
            if (isOdd(i) && isOdd(j))
                array[i][j] = 1;
            else
                array[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i=0; i<9; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j<9; j++) {
        array[i][j] = ((j%2 && i%2)?1:0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want the column index to be odd and the row index odd so the correct condition for a `1` in your 2-d array would be:

`(i%2==1) && (j%2==1)`

Answer (score 0):

A general approach for solving big problems is to break them apart into smaller problems.

---

**Exercise 1**

You are given two functions:

- `print_zeroes` prints `000000000`
- `print_zeroes_and_ones` prints `010101010`

Write a single loop that alternates calling these functions so as to print the grid you want.

---

**Exercise 2**

Write the function `print_zeroes`.

---

**Exercise 3**

Write the function `print_zeroes_and_ones`.

---

**Extra Credit**

- Write a single function `print_a_line` that takes an argument and picks between doing `print_zeroes` and `prints_zeroes_and_ones`
- Write a loop that uses `print_a_line` to print the grid.
- Manually inline the function (i.e. replace the function call with the code of the function) and try to simplify it.

Comment: I'm curious: is the downvote because I answer "how to solve problems like these" rather than provide a complete working solution for this specific problem, because people are experienced enough to do the whole thing in one go and think everyone else should be the same, or something else?